# Dynamic Time Warping - Comparing Values

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, speech, mfcc

Apologies if this is in the wrong forum.

Ok, so I'm trying to compare two different speech signals and I have come into a problem. Here goes:

I have split the signal into blocks, and I have computed the MFCC coefficients of each block. I then use a DTW algorithm to compare the (inputted) signal to the training signal.

EDIT (Would this algorithm work)?

I have updated the algorithm (Written it from the Wikipedia article):

It now handles 2D vectors, instead of 1D.. I think this is where I was going wrong because, hence it was printing out a range of numbers rather than just 1.

If the inputted values for (actual, training) MFCC are exactly the same, then the difference is then "0" there are no differences. I need to check with a training value, but, does this algorithm look right?

Comment: It doesn't seem you understand the algorithm, probably you need to read more about it. As a result of MFCC calculation you should have a two-dimensional array or a sequence of frames. You should use Euclidean distance to calculate distance between frames. You should use DTW to compare sequences of frames.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks for the reply :) Yes, from computing the MFCC I have a 2D array containing 13 values (for each block).. Do I therefore need to calculate the Euclidean distance and then DTW? I'm confused about this. Thanks

Comment: In DTW a distance function is used. Such distance function should calculate Euclidean distance between frames. To avoid confusion read about DTW on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Please see my updated post, I have edited it to show the algorithm.. Does this looks correct, and, is there anything else I need to implement? The algorithm seems to follow the link that you provided..

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev P.S. I compare 13 values (coefficients) these are what gives me the values (above) I don't understand what you mean, hence I'm getting confused and every tutorial / paper I read tells me to pass in two vectors (actual[0]....[#], training[0]....[#]) sorry if this isn't making sense

Comment: Every tutorial and paper is correct and you are not. You need to pass two vectors: actual[0], actual[1] and so on. The thing you don't understand is that actual[0] is a vector itself {28.6696, 65.8777, 44.2725, 31.6083, 42.6541, 38.4104, 26.6311, 34.9188, 37.2065, 25.2479, 41.5969, 54.2681, 37.0685, 26.207} So actual is vector of vectors and actual[0] is a vector of 13 coeffcients

Comment: In wikipedia algorithm is simplified and calculates distance between numbers, you need to calculate distance between mfcc vectors instead.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks.. Ok, I kinda get it! Let's say I have a vector that is of 2D called "Yes1" and it contains `yes[0]` which has 13 coefficients and `yes[1]` contains another set of coefficients I then pass these to the DTW so instead of `DTW(actual[0], training[0])` it would be: `DTW(actual[0], actual[0....])` but then how do I compare this data with the training? :S

Comment: Using the same code from Wikipedia, just updated for vectors instead of numbers.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Hey, I have been doing some reading and working on some algorithms. I have edited my post, would this algorithm work? Just want your opinions.. I have tried.

Comment: It got way worse, I don't understand your post anymore.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I'm sorry. I have updated the post and added some code. I hope this makes sense, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23999/discussion-between-phorce-and-nikolay-shmyrev)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Hey, I have updated my post with the new algorithm I wrote.. Please could you check it and tell me if this is the correct method for implementation? The result I get (for the training/actual) vectors is: 10 Thank you

Comment: Now it's looks more or less correct